# Modern Warfare 3 (MW3) Strict Nat on PS3 and 3G Dongle

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3, networking

I am using a levelone wbr-6800 3g router and a 3g dongle. I am trying to get an open NAT with Mordern Warfare 3 on a ps3. Basically [these are the results](http://www.speedtest.net/result/1955928480.png) I get when pinging a server in CA.

My problem is supposed to be solved [by this](http://community.callofduty.com/message/37570)

I have setup my router according to that faq and I have attached screen shots.

1. my router IP address is 192.168.0.1
2. I have disabled dhcp and I'm hardcoding the DNS addresses. The IP address(static) assigned to the ps3 is 192.168.0.3
3. I have placed the ps3 IP address in the dmz as shown here:

[image: dmz]

4. I have also forwarded the ports needed by psn and mw3 as shown here in accordance to the faq.
5. My basic setup is as shown here

[image: Setup]

With that my router should have a moderate or open NAT but it still comes up as strict.

The router also has another section for special applications but I'm not sure how to work it.

[image: special applications]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your router has an ethernet port, I would suggest hard wiring the connection. I have the same setup, and it works, but the Ping situation is pretty much an unsolvable problem, mainly because you're using 3g.

I would suggest you get a land-line based network connection.

The problem with 3g is because for one, it allows for high quantities of data transfer by sending highly compressed, albeit infrequent, packets. Additionally, the packets travel along the following path, more or less:

PS3 > WiFi router > 3G modem > Local Cellular tower > Cellular Hub> Cellular HQ > ISP DNS > ISP Hub > and so on...

This isn't exactly accurate, but it's roughly how it works.

> #### For Example
>
> This is what Happens when I ping Google through my 3G modem, connected directly to my laptop.
>
> Tracing route to www.l.google.com [74.125.71.99]
>   over a maximum of 30 hops:
>
> 1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
>
> 2   725 ms   419 ms   178 ms  10.159.130.73
>
> 3   143 ms    79 ms   138 ms  10.159.161.56
>
> 4   116 ms    99 ms    99 ms  10.40.128.2
>
> 5    89 ms    99 ms    99 ms  10.159.40.185
>
> 6    97 ms    99 ms    99 ms  10.159.52.150
>
> 7   127 ms   109 ms   119 ms  202.138.144.241
>
> 8   127 ms   177 ms   130 ms  202.138.145.53
>
> 9   118 ms   119 ms   148 ms  202.138.145.78
>
> 10   146 ms   119 ms   119 ms  209.85.248.62
>
> 11   137 ms   139 ms   147 ms  209.85.253.69
>
> 12   126 ms   144 ms   129 ms  216.239.48.226
>
> 13   107 ms   129 ms   125 ms  hx-in-f99.1e100.net [74.125.71.99]
>
> Trace complete.

As you can see, this is an inordinate number of hops. I suggest you try the same:

> #### Trace route
>
> 1) Press [Windows Key] + R
>
> 2) type "cmd" (without quotation marks) and press enter
>
> 3) type "tracert [website URL]" and press enter
>
> 4) let it run through, this might take some time.
>
> 5) You should have a report like above.

If your own Trace Route settings are similar to my own, then I would advise against playing games online until you have a landline based connection.

That's pretty much the only solution I can think of, and am even in the process of getting a landline connection myself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The number of hops isnt the problem. i just tracert to google aswell and i got 14 hops and i have a landline.
The ping i have is a lot better though (around 1-5 ms)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that after getting my old router replaced with a new one, I was able to get my NAT from strict to open.